# How can I clear .NET's reflection cache?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, reflection

If I use reflection to retrieve an assembly, it will seek out the assembly and then cache it.  I can tell this because, if it fails to find the assembly, it won't find it even after I add it to the correct location.  If it finds the assembly and I remove it, it still uses the assembly it found and cached.

I know I'm not the only one to have this issue:  [Clear .Net Reflection cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274310/clear-net-reflection-cache)

The code I'm using to get the assembly is the following - and I make this call every time (not caching myself):

```
// Try to get the assembly referenced.
Assembly reflectedAssembly;
try
{
    reflectedAssembly = Assembly.Load(assembly);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    errorMessage = string.Format("Could not find assembly '{0}'", assembly);
    result = null;
    return false;
}
```

What I want to know is if there's a way to clear the reflection cache without restarting the process.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `Assembly.LoadFrom` maybe?

Comment: What are you passing to Assembly.Load? a string? a byte array? an AssemblyName instance?

Comment: @Fernando - I'm passing in a string along these lines:  "ClassLibrary1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=d48aa85d4ceaf047"

Comment: @M.Babcock - I'm using the GAC in order to allow easy versioning of assemblies, so loading from a file isn't applicable.  Also, it behaves the same - if I don't have the file, then I add it, it still won't find it.  (I can't test the other way, since the file gets locked and I can't remove it, but I imagine it's the same.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't unload assemblies in .Net - you can however shut down an app domain (which is where assemblies are loaded into).

Comment: Not entirely correct. There is a special kind of assembly that can be unloaded. But assemblies loaded from files can never be unloaded. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932.aspx It's also possible to load assemblies in a way that they are shared between AppDomains, and don't get unloaded just because you unload one of them.

Comment: "Assembly loading   Reflection emit is the only mechanism that is supported for loading collectible assemblies. Assemblies that are loaded by any other form of assembly loading cannot be unloaded."
From the article linked.  So, to unload, I'd have to dynamically generate the assemblies.
Thanks to both of you for the answer - what I'm trying to do isn't possible.

Comment: Although, the concept of unloading is a bit different than the concept of loading one that was never loaded - the cache won't try to get it again if it failed once.  (Probably part of the same concept, though - that it will keep the results of the operation regardless of what they are.)